# Not receiving push notifications from Firebase to iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I've uploaded development and production certificates on FCM, Enabled push notification in Capabilities, Placed GoogleService-Info.plist in my project.
I've tried making another Google account and trying again all the procedure but nothing worked for me.

I tried sending notification to single device token, but it gets rejected showing "Invalid registration token.check token format"

Below is the code I tried.

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    NSError *configureError;
[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);



GAI *gai = [GAI sharedInstance];
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
gai.logger.logLevel = kGAILogLevelVerbose;

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
    UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
} else {

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0

        [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        }];


        [FIRMessaging messaging].remoteMessageDelegate = self;
#endif
    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}


[FIRApp configure];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                             name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];
    return YES;


}
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[self connectToFirebase];


 application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *) application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:( void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

}

#pragma mark -- Custom Firebase code


- (void)tokenRefreshCallback:(NSNotification *) notification{
NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];

[self connectToFirebase];
}

-(void) connectToFirebase{

[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
     if ( error != nil)
     {

     }
     else
     {

     }
 }];
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {

    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}}


 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {

NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {

}


completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}

 - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {
   NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
if (userInfo[kGCMMessageIDKey]) {

}

completionHandler();
  }

- (void)connectToFcm {

if (![[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token]) {
    return;
}

[[FIRMessaging messaging] disconnect];

[[FIRMessaging messaging] connectWithCompletion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {

    } else {

    }
}];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"PUSH ERROR: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
NSLog(@"%@",deviceToken);
}

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {

}

- (void)tokenRefreshNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {

NSString *refreshedToken = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];    
NSLog(@"%@",refreshedToken);

[self connectToFcm];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{

[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

Comment: Which token are you using? Are you using device token?

Comment: try to send using select app . instead of single device . or ensure that you have upload correct .p12 file in project setting tab.

Comment: if you have recently add .p12 then you need to redownload google configuration file and replace with old one.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina yes device token.

Comment: @KKRocks I tried sending with selecting app too

Comment: did you upload correct .p12 file to your project setting ?

Comment: @KKRocks Yes.  I uploaded both development as well production aps.cer and aps_development.cer, their .p12

Comment: you need to only upload .p12 only not .cer file.

Comment: @KKRocks I created certificates from developer portal, Saved em in keychain, exported them and created .p12 file and then uploaded to FCM

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using **device token** to send push notifications from firebase console. If that's true, you shouldn't use device token. Instead, Firebase will give you FCMRegistration token. Try to use that token to send a notification to that specific device.

Excerpted from my article.

> To send a push notification to the particular device we need the
>   device token. When you run the application on your device(Not on a
>   simulator) and if your setup is correct, your console will print
>   Device token and FCM registration token. Both are similar but not the
>   same. Device token we use when we are sending push notifications
>   through some third party services or our own server. We use FCM
>   registration token if we are sending push notifications through
>   firebase console. So in our case, we take FCM registration token which
>   is printed on the console.

[image]
Below is my article on [How to send push notifications using firebase](https://insights.nimblechapps.com/app-development/ios-app-development/how-to-use-firebase-to-send-notifications-in-ios)

**Additonal Info:** In case, if you want to try checking whether your push notifications code configured correctly or not use third party library like [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)
But this time use *device token* in pusher to check.

Comment: I tried this and FCM rejected it showing it's invalid

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is the issue you are faced.

You need to upload correct .p12 file for Your APNS .

You need to simply Goto **Project Setting** then under **Cloud Messaging**

Here you need to add your .p12 file.

[image]

After uploading you need to redownload configuration file and replace with old one.

**Solution 2**

I have upload swift code if you can understand then convert it to objective-c because i don't have objective-c code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
      FirebaseApp.configure()
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
  }

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
    var token: String = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
      token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", deviceToken[i] as CVarArg)
    }

    print(token)
  }
```

In **capabilities** tab, it should be like also

[image]

Comment: I did it too. :(

Comment: @Shikha Sharma can i add my swift code which is working fine in my project.

Comment: Yeah , It will help me. though i need objective-s but it's fine atlas i'll get some help

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *)
    {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions([.Badge, .Sound, .Alert])          { (granted, error) in
                if granted
                {
                //self.registerCategory()
             }
         }
         // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
         FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    }
    else
    {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =  UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert,.Badge,.Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }          
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()        
    //Configuring Firebase
    FIRApp.configure()
    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)     
     return true
}

//Receive Remote Notification on Background
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)
{
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Prod)
}

func tokenRefreshNotification(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
    {
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
    }
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}

func connectToFcm()
{
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
    }
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
{            
    connectToFcm()
}
```